OR logic using the + operator not working in Filter function
I am using OR logic in a filter function using the + operator to filter rows for which the start date or end date falls in a specific month. However, no matches are found in the filter evaluation.
Sheet image

Details:
Project Name, start date, and end date are in columns A, B & C.
Columns E-H have month number in row 1 and month name in row 2.
The filter formula is in E3:H3 and is as follows:
FILTER($A$2:$A$5,MONTH($B$2:$B$5)=E1+MONTH($C$2:$C$5)=E1)

I want the filter to return projects that will be active in a particular month i.e. either start date, end date, or both falling in that month.

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of winging it from screenshots), the recommended method is creating a markdown table. Use this table generator to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Another way is to share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing


You may try this in Cell_E3:
=filter($A2:$A5,byrow(map($B2:$B5,$C2:$C5,lambda(c,d,torow(eomonth(sequence(days(d,c)+1,1,c),)))),lambda(Σ,xmatch(eomonth(date(2024,E1,1),),Σ))))


You may try this:
=ArrayFormula(LET(startDate,B3:B6,
                  endDate,C3:C6,
                  proj,A3:A6,
                  filterStartDate,E1:G1,
                  rowPos,ROW(startDate),
                  dateCond,(EOMONTH(startDate,-1)+1=filterStartDate)+(EOMONTH(endDate,-1)+1=filterStartDate),
                  getRowperDate,IF(dateCond,rowPos,),
                  removeBlanks,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(getRowperDate,,9^9)))," ")),
                  getProj,XLOOKUP(removeBlanks,rowPos,proj,),
                  getProj))


Note: I changed the month numbers into the start dates of the months so that we can incorporate the year.
